# Get mousewheel anywhere on screen? (Python or C++)

Tags: winapi, pywin32

In the Windows API,

```
x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
```

...will get the mouse position regardless of whether it's inside your window or whether your program even has a GUI. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx)) ([Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698635/geting-cursor-position-in-python))

Is there a similar function to get the scrollwheel (mousewheel)'s current rotation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472234/intercept-all-wm-mousewheel-messages

Answer (score 4):

The mouse wheel's rotation is not an absolute value like the cursor position. Rather, the wheel position is the *delta* from the previous wheel position, either positive or negative, expressed as a multiple of 120 (120 = 1 line.). So, if the user scrolls up three lines, the delta might be +360 whereas if they scroll down three lines the delta might be -360.

You can keep an internal variable that you update every time your app gets a [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message which will allow you to track the cumulative change in rotation since your app started. So if a user scrolls up 10 lines and down 20 lines the cumulative delta would be -1200.

Comment: your app doesn't get a WM_MOUSEWHEEL message if it's not the active window  so that doesn't particularly help (unless there is some trick to getting those messages?)