# Intercept all WM_MOUSEWHEEL messages

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I've been searching through the Windows API, looking for a way to intercept all WM_MOUSESCROLL messages before they hit their perspective message queues. After intercepting I need to change a few things about them and send them to a different [or the same] message queue.

I need to do this fairly efficiently as it will be running on top of a fairly large application.

Any Ideas on how I can achieve this? I've yet to find a way.

Comment: Do you mean `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`? There is no `WM_MOUSESCROLL` message. Also, when you say *all*, do you mean all for your thread, all for your process, or all throughout the system?

Comment: You are correct, I meant WM_MOUSEWHEEL, and I mean ALL, all throughout the system, and I really would like to be the first to receive it.

Comment: There's no way you can guarantee being the first to receive it (by application of the "What if two programs did this?" principle). But if you use a low-level hook, you'll get it before the input system dispatches it, which may be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is an unmanaged interception using a [low level mouse event hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). see [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) for more info.

Comment: I summarized that MS article once in the following SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497024/how-to-detect-mouse-clicks/7497173#7497173

Comment: @ChristopheGeers: thats awesome, much more readable than the MS one

Comment: I tried this and it works great, 50% of the time though. Sometimes I will receive the message before the the window I'm trying to modify these messages for, sometimes after. This changes the applications desired behavior. Btw, I don't own the window, however, it's handle is easily accessible.

Comment: @AdmiralNelson: then there is something wrong with the hook, as the LL one is guaranteed to be called before its posted to the message queue. you may also want to try `WH_CALLWNDPROC`, which gets all messages before they get dispatched to the WndProc.

Answer (score 0):

When using MFC you can use [PreTranslateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or search for the `WndProc` function in a custom framework and see if it provides similar functionality. Otherwise the mouse hooking is good idea. Especially when you want to do it globally.