# Python get mouse x, y position on click

Tags: python, python-2.7

Coming from IDL, I find it quite hard in python to get the x-y position of the mouse on a single left click using a method that is not an overkill as in tkinter. Does anyone know about a python package that contains a method simply returning x-y when the mouse is clicked (similar to the cursor method in IDL)?

Comment: I've voted to re-open this question. It was closed as "too broad" which I disagree with. The OP is asking for a method to obtain coordinates on mouse click without having to resort to `tkinter` overkill (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501192/how-to-display-picture-and-get-mouse-click-coordinate-on-it) What's too broad about this?

Answer (score 25):

There are a number of libraries you could use.  Here are two third party ones:

**Using PyAutoGui**

A powerful GUI automation library allows you to get screen size, control the mouse, keyboard and more.

To get the position you just need to use the `position()` function.  Here is an example:

```
>>>import pyautogui
>>>pyautogui.position()
(1358, 146)
>>>
```

Where `1358` is the X position and `146` is the Y position.

Relavent [link to the documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)

**Using Pynput**

Another (more minimalistic) library is Pynput:

```
>>> from pynput.mouse import Controller
>>> mouse = Controller()
>>> mouse.position
(1182, 153)
>>>
```

Where `1182` is the X position and `153` is the second.

[Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html#controlling-the-mouse)

This library is quite easy to learn, does not require dependencies, making this library ideal for small tasks like this (where PyAutoGui would be an overkill).  Once again though,  it does not provide so many features though.

**Windows Specific:**

For platform dependant, but default library options (though you may still consider them overkills) can be found here: [Getting cursor position in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698635/getting-cursor-position-in-python/24567802).

Comment: But how to execute this *when the mouse is clicked*?

Comment: PyAutoGui uses PyScreeze to continuously capture the screen, I assume since the CPU usage is extremely high for something as simple as mouse tracking. Now *that's* what *I* consider overkill.

Answer (score 14):

Using [`PyMouse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMouse):

```
>>> import pymouse
>>> mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()
>>> mouse.position()
(231L, 479L)
```

Comment: See also the library [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput), which integrates PyMouse's code and appears to be more current. One of its dependencies, PyHook, is officially 32 bit only, but a third-party 64 bit installer can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook).

Comment: You can listen for mouse click events by subclassing the `PyMouseEvent` class. See the "Clickonacci" example on the PyUserInput page.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get the position *when the mouse is clicked*.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, for plot or images, it is possible to use the `matplotlib` tool called `ginput`.
At every click of the mouse the `[x,y]` coordinates of the selected point are stored in a variable.

```
# show image
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)

# select point
yroi = plt.ginput(0,0)
```

using `ginput(0,0)` you can select any points on the plot or image.

here the link for the `ginput documentation`

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html

Answer (score 3):

I made this the other day.
It a function to get color or pos on right click / left click:

```
#Add Any helpfull stuff in functions here for later use
def GetMouseInfos(WhatToGet="leaving emety will get you x and y", GetXOnly=False, GetYOnly=False, GetColor=False, Key='Right', OverrideKey=False):#gets color of whats under Key cursor on right click
    try:
        import win32api
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("win32api not found, to install do pip install pywin32")
    try:
        import time
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("time not found, to install do pip install time?")
    try:
        import pyautogui
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("py auto gui not found, to install do pip install pyautogui")
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
    #above checks if needed modules are installed if not tells user
    #code below is to get all varibles needed
    #---------------------------------------------------------------
    print(WhatToGet)
    if OverrideKey:
        Key_To_click = Key
    if Key == 'Left':
        Key_To_click = 0x01
    if Key == 'Right':
        Key_To_click = 0x02
    if Key == 'Wheel':
        Key_To_click = 0x04
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(Key_To_click)  # Left button up = 0 or 1. Button down = -127 or -128
    IsTrue = True
    while IsTrue:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(Key_To_click)
        if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
            state_left = a
            if a < 0:
                global Xpos, Ypos
                Xpos, Ypos = win32api.GetCursorPos()
                x, y = pyautogui.position()
                pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
            else:
                posnowX, posnowY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
                win32api.SetCursorPos((posnowX, posnowY))
                IsTrue = False#remove this for it to keep giving coords on click without it just quitting after 1 click
        time.sleep(0.001)
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    #The Code above is the code to get all varibles and code below is for the user to get what he wants
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    if GetXOnly: #Checks if we should get Only X (def options) the command to do this would be GetKeyInfos("Click To get X ONLY", True)
        if GetYOnly:
            return(Xpos , Ypos)
        if GetColor:
            return(Xpos, pixelColor)
        return(Xpos)
    if GetYOnly: #Checks if we should get Only Y (def options) the command to do this would be GetKeyInfos("Click To get X ONLY",False, True)
        if GetXOnly:
            return(Xpos , Ypos)
        if GetColor:
            return(Ypos, pixelColor) 
        return(Ypos)
    if GetColor:
        return(pixelColor) #Checks 
    return(Xpos, Ypos)
# getKeyinfos("Anything here without any other guidelines will give u x and y only on right click")
```

Answer (score 3):

How to Capture Mouse Click Coordinates (x, y) Without Tkinter?

First, install pynput (use pip install pynput (without the 'i')).
Then, copy and paste this script into your editor:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button


# Function called on a mouse click
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    # Check if the left button was pressed
    if pressed and button == Button.left:
        # Print the click coordinates
        print(f'x={x} and y={y}')


# Initialize the Listener to monitor mouse clicks
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

It's as simple as that! This script captures the coordinates (x, y) of the mouse when clicking with the left button.

Happy coding!

Comment: That's short. Although, what is `x=x` and `y=y`? Do you need this? How would I stop the loop, if e.g. I acquired two set of coordinates and want to continue with the program using these values?

Answer (score 2):

Use pygame

```
import pygame

mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

This returns the x and y position of the mouse.

See this website: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_pos

Comment: if I use this I get `pygame.error: video system not initialized`, and if I use `pygame.init()` then I get a constant (0,0) position wherever my cursor is.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get the position *when the mouse is clicked*.

Comment: That returns the x & y position of the mouse in a pygame window, not in the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for canvas with tkinter:

```
def callback(event):  
    print("clicked at: ", event.x, event.y)  

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

For turtle :

```
def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)
```

Comment: add `turtle.mainloop()` in the end so the screen remains open when you click.

Answer (score -3):

You all are making it too hard, its just as easy as:

```
import pyautogui as pg

pos = pg.position()

# for x pos
print(pos[0])

# for y pos
print(pos[1])
```

Comment: This didn't answer the question. He specifically asked to return the co-ordinates, when the mouse button is clicked, without using tkinter.