# Co-ordinates of Mouse when clicked - Python

Tags: python, mouseevent, coordinates

I want to create a python script that stores the mouse click's co-ordiantes. The co-ordinates should save in a file.
I came across the following thread but I couldn't get it working.
The script should capture mouse cordinates all over the desktop and not to a particular window/application.

[Python get mouse x, y position on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848951/python-get-mouse-x-y-position-on-click)

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid "I couldn't get it working" is too broad to be answerable. Please show the code you tried and explain what didn't work at minimum. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python should help.

Comment: @ggorlen I tried to use pyautogui and pymouse.
It shows the x,y co-ordinates of the mouse when i click on run and nothing else.
As mentioned i want to create python code that shows the x,y coordinates of mouse whenever it is clicked on any application or at desktop.
I am sorry if my question could not be understood.

>>> import pymouse

>>> mouse = pymouse.PyMouse()

>>> mouse.position()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
     print(x,y)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

The result of above code is:

```
830 345 Button.left True
830 345 Button.left False
```

The values of above code will print twice i.e one for co-ordinate value for button pressed and one co-ordinate value for button released.

So to get both the co-ordinates of mouse click event and released event use the above code.

So to print the value of co-ordinates where mouse button is clicked use the below code:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed == True:
        print(x,y)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

AND

So to print the value of co-ordinates where mouse button is released use the below code:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed == False:
        print(x,y)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

Comment: @AniketPaul please find the above solution

Comment: it prints the value twice

Comment: @AniketPaul Check the above solution.