# get position of mouse in python on click or button press

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

I want to get the `x, y` position of the mouse (in `windows 11`) and use this position in the rest of the code.

I have tried two different modules but neither seem to work.

1. pyautogui  (for a mouse click or button press)
2. keyboard (for a button press)

So far, i am able to get the current position (with `pyautogui`), but i **cannot break out of the while loop** to proceed to the next piece of code or even return the function.

Here is the function with my attempts:

```py
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard

def spam_ordinates():
    ''' function to determin the mouse coordinates'''

    print('press "x" key to lock position...')

    while True:
        # Check if the left mouse button is clicked
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(pyautogui.displayMousePosition())

        # various methods i have tried ...
        if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            print('x key pressed...')
            break

        if pyautogui.mouseDown():
            print("Mouse clicked!")
            break

        if pyautogui.keyDown('x'):
            print('x key pressed (autogui)...')
            break

    # Get the current mouse position
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print(f'spam at position: {x}, {y}')

    return x, y

# call function
ords = spam_ordinates()
```

i see answers like this:
[Python get mouse x, y position on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848951/python-get-mouse-x-y-position-on-click), but unfortunately it doesn't actually return a value on the `mouse click` or `button press`.

So, how can i break out of the while loop such that the function returns the `x, y` position of the mouse?

**update**

it appears as though `print(pyautogui.displayMousePosition())` was preventing the code from breaking out of the while loop.

I am not sure why, but commenting out that line corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that for some reason the `print(pyautogui.displayMousePosition())` line of code was creating problems from breaking out of the loop.

when the above `print` statement was removed, i was able to use any of the modules:

- pynput
- keyboard

so this code works with the `keyboard module:

```py
def spam_ordinates():
    ''' function to determin the mouse coordinates'''

    print('press "x" key to lock position...')

    while True:
        # Check if x key is pressed
        time.sleep(0.1)

        if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            print('x key pressed...')
            break

    # Get the current mouse position
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print(f'spam at position: {x}, {y}')

    return x, y
```

I cannot explain completely why `print(pyautogui.displayMousePosition())` caused this error, other than it must have been blocking the `if statements` that would have evoked the break.

I post this answer in case anybody else encounters the same.