# How to find mouse X and Y in python, simple

Tags: python, mouse

Making a pong game and I don't know how to get the paddle to be where the mouse x is.

I've looked at some more pages but those require python extensions. I want to keep it simple.

Comment: Why do you not want to use any third party libraries? For this task they are often more simple. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848951/python-get-mouse-x-y-position-on-click?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698635/getting-cursor-position-in-python

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you plan to show a paddle if you have the coordinates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get mouse x, y position on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848951/python-get-mouse-x-y-position-on-click)