# Using time module for time check - Ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython

my question is actually quite easy but I get stuck with this issue.

I want to set timer to 2 second and then check if the mouse is still in the same poit as previous.

example: I detect the point of the mouse as (250, 500) and then put timer to 2 secs and check again where is the pointer now.

would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Do check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698635/getting-cursor-position-in-python/24567802 to get mouse coordinates. You just need to compare the coordinates every 2 seconds to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Detecting the mouse position is not the problem for me.
the question is how can I detect the mouse position, set timer  to 2 secs and then chech again

Answer (score 0):

you can use time.sleep in cycle for

```
import time

for i in range(0,2):# range: 0,1 = 2 iteration = 2 sec
    time.sleep(1)
```