# Tkinter: How to track mouse position after mouse leaving gui app's display area?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried this
[How to get the text cursor position in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698635/how-to-get-the-text-cursor-position-in-windows), but it still not work, when mouse leaves gui's boundingbox, it does not update mouse position anymore
What I want to do is to let mouse move out my python app's area, and let it move on other part of the screen, and get the position of it relative to the screen

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref


class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_long), ("y", c_long)]



def queryMousePosition():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return { "x": pt.x, "y": pt.y}


pos = queryMousePosition()
print(pos)
```

Comment: I get it by `flags, hcursor, (x, y)  = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()  # Get cursor position` in WIN10.

Comment: I think an easier method of retrieving mouse position is using the `pyautogui` library (`pip install pyautogui`) and then using the [`.position()`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=position#general-functions) function then you also probably need an `.after` loop to keep track of the position all the time if that is what you need

Comment: You can use tkinter `.winfo_pointerxy()` to get the mouse position periodically using tkinter `.after()`.  `.winfo_pointerxy()` works even the mouse cursor is out of the tkinter window.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest method in my opinion is using the PyAutoGui library. You can install it using the command `pip install pyautogui` or `python -m pip install pyautogui` and using the `pyautogui.position()` method inside the library